# Одна информация под другой

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня такая проблема,если нажать на первую картинку,то высветится информация,если нажать потом на вторую,то эта информация выйдет под первой,как мне сделать так,чтобы они не выходили одна  под другую ,а просто создавались заново

```
    <style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
#somedesc {
  font-size:x-large;
  text-align:center;
}

}
</style> 

    <script>



    $(document).ready(function(){

          function toggledescription(el) {
    var selector = el.getAttribute('descSelector');
    $(selector).toggleClass('hidden');
  }

  $("img[descSelector]").click(function(e) {
    toggledescription(this);
        $('.img-2').css('position','absolute').css('bottom','20px').css('left','100px')
         });
    $("img[descSelector]").click(function(e) {
    toggledescription(this);
        $('.img-3').css('position','absolute').css('bottom','20px').css('left','300px')
         });

  $("img[descSelector]").click(function(e) {
    toggledescription(this);
        $('.img-4').css('position','absolute').css('bottom','20px').css('left','500px')
         });

  $("img[descSelector]").click(function(e) {
    toggledescription(this);
        $('.img-5').css('position','absolute').css('bottom','20px').css('left','700px')
         });

  $("img[descSelector]").click(function(e) {
    toggledescription(this);
        $('.img-6').css('position','absolute').css('bottom','20px').css('left','900px')
         });


<img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/2.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt='' class='img-2' width='150' />
<img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/3.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt='' class='img-3' width='150' />
<img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/4.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt='' class='img-4' width='150' />
<img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/5.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt='' class='img-5' width='150' />
<img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/6.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt='' class='img-6' width='150' />
<div id="somedesc" class="hidden"><p><b>Лев</b></p>Вид хищных млекопитающих, один из четырёх представителей рода пантер, относящегося к подсемейству больших кошек в составе семейства кошачьих. Наряду с тигром — самая крупная из ныне живущих кошек, масса некоторых самцов может достигать 250 кг.</div>
<div id="somedes" class="hidden"><p><b>Что-то другое</b></p>Бла бла бла.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то такое нужно?)

```js
$('.image_cart').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  else {
    $('.image_cart.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.image_cart {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image_cart::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.image_cart img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.image_cart h3 {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.image_cart:not(.active) h3,
.image_cart:not(.active) p {
  display: none;
}

.image_cart.active h3,
.image_cart.active p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="https://files.adme.ru/files/news/part_129/1294015/10270765-Screenshot7-1000-5d66fb2644-1484652637.jpg" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="" class="img-2" />
  <h3>Лев</h3>
  <p>Вид хищных млекопитающих, один из четырёх представителей рода пантер, относящегося к подсемейству больших кошек в составе семейства кошачьих. Наряду с тигром — самая крупная из ныне живущих кошек, масса некоторых самцов может достигать 250 кг.</p>
</div>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="https://www.epochtimes.ru/eet-content/uploads/2017/09/db933710cce7d3a1df3f42faecda53fa-676x450.jpg" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="" class="img-3" />
  <h3>Барс</h3>
  <p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
</div>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="http://www.nat-geo.ru/upload/iblock/ebe/ebe537cd5d0627d35abaa21d17f900b0.jpg" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="" class="img-4" />
  <h3>Тигр</h3>
  <p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
</div>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="https://img2.ntv.ru/home/news/20180129/puma_io.jpg" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="" class="img-5" />
  <h3>Пума</h3>
  <p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
</div>
```

Comment: а как сделать так,чтобы картинки были снизу,а информация посередине сверху?

Comment: @ХаххирЗачир, обновил ответ)